# phpseclib Cannot connect to server. Error 111. Connection refused

Tags: sftp, phpseclib

I am trying to connect to **sftp server** using **phpseclib**. But I am getting error

> "Cannot connect to server. Error 111. Connection refused"

Code is working fine on local machine. However when I upload it to godaddy I git the error

> "Cannot connect to server. Error 111. Connection refused"

Can I use phpseclib on shared hosting?

How I can fix that error?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: That looks like an error that `fsockopen`would produce. I'd try just doing `$fsock = fsockopen('whatever.com', 22, $errno, $errstr); echo $errstr;` and seeing if you get the error with that. If so then email godaddy. Email them the script and email them the error you're getting. There's not really much you can do on your end to resolve the issue if my hypothesis is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall has opened port 22. You can use telnet to check this as well